# Hamiltonian for a free particle in polar coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

If we consider a particle that starts at $(0,d)$ and moves along $y=d$ at constant speed $v=v\hat i$ then in polar co-ordinates, $r=((vt)^2 + d^2)^{1/2}$ and $\tan \theta = \frac {d}{vt}$

Its $a_r=0$ and $a_\theta=0$ which is easily calculated by using the formulas $$a_r =\ddot r - r \dot\theta^2$$
and
$$a_\theta= r \ddot \theta+2\dot r\dot \theta$$

The Hamiltonian for this case in polar coordinates can be written as:
$$H=\frac{p_r^2}{2m} + \frac{p_\theta^2}{2mr^2}$$
where ${p_r}=m \dot r$ and ${p_\theta}=mr^2 \dot \theta $

From this, $$\frac{\partial H}{\partial r}=-\dot p_r\neq 0 $$ since there is $r^2$ in denominator of the 2nd term , this implies that $a_r$ shouldn't be zero. But in fact, it is.

What is the discrepancy when I apply the Hamiltonian approach?

I got this doubt due to a discussion in Liboff's "Introductory QM" where he writes:

> We may also consider the dynamics of a free particle in spherical coordinates.
> The Hamiltonian is
> $$H=\frac{p_r^2}{2m} + \frac{p_\theta^2}{2mr^2}+\frac{p_\phi^2}{2mr^2\sin^2 \theta}$$
> Only $\phi$ is cyclic, and we immediately conclude that $p_\phi$ (or equivalently, $L_z$) is
> constant. However, $p_r$ and $p_\theta$ are not constant. From Hamilton's equations, we
> obtain
> $$\dot p_r=\frac{p_\theta^2}{mr^3}+\frac{p_\phi^2}{mr^3\sin^2 \theta}$$
> $$\dot p_\theta=\frac{p_\phi^2 \cos \theta}{mr^2\sin^3 \theta}$$
> These centripetal terms were interpreted above. In this manner we find that the
> rectilinear, constant-velocity motion of a free particle, when cast in a spherical
> coordinate frame, involves accelerations in the r and $\theta$ components of motion.
> These accelerations arise from an inappropriate choice of coordinates. In simple
> language: Fitting a straight line to spherical coordinates gives peculiar results.

Doesn't this reasoning also apply for a 2D case as I have mentioned above?

The considerations are same : a rectilinearly moving point at constant velocity. In the 3D case mentioned in the book, the non-zero radial and azimuthal components of acceleration come out non-zero but they come out zero in my case. What's the difference? (apart from moving from 3D to 2D which I think shouldn't make a difference)

Comment: Can you explain why that implies $a_r \neq 0$? It might help to see things a bit clearer if you integrate your second equation $a_\theta$ wrt time and substitute $\dot{\theta}$ into your radial equation.

Comment: Did you blow a sign? $ma_r= \dot{p}_r-\dot{p}_\theta^2/mr^3=0$ by your EOM.

Comment: @Rumplestillskin Since, $\dot p$ is non-zero, then radial force and acceleration is non-zero. This is what I reasoned. What is wrong with it?

Comment: @Rumplestillskin Please also check the edit I made. Also, do you mean that having a non-zero $\dot p_r$ doesn't imply a $a_r=0$ since $\dot p_r=m\ddot r$ while $a_r$ has a term of $r \dot \theta^2$ as well? I think this was the mistake I was making. But then how does Liboff conclude from non -zero expressions of $p_\theta$ that there is an azimuthal acceleration?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Sorry. I do not understand. Where did I blow up the sign? $a_r$ comes zero. That I have calculated and it is correct.

Comment: For free motion, *all* projections of the acceleration vanish, as you illustrated. Liboff's "nvolves accelerations in the r and  components of motion" is misleading. You now have the right idea here.  You might repeat your exercise, with the same type result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot imagine what discrepancy you are talking about. The EOM yields
$$ \partial_ r \left (\frac{p_r^2}{2m} + \frac{p_\theta^2}{2mr^2}\right )=-\dot p_r, $$
which amounts to
$$
\frac{p_\theta^2}{mr^3} = \dot p_r. 
$$
It is quite misleading to think of it as "the" radial force, as it willfully skips the centripetal acceleration.

The radial acceleration you found first, written in terms of canonical momenta, is
$$
ma_r= \dot p_r -\frac{p_\theta^2}{mr^3},
$$
so, given the EOM above, it vanishes. Where is the discrepancy?

Comment: Understood. Now its obvious. It was a stupid mistake. Also now I understand that the extra 2nd term in the 1st eqn given in Liboff is the reason $a_r$ is not equal to zero there. This is because thats the 3-D Hamiltonian.

Comment: I had thought that since writing EOM of linear trajectory in 3-D soherical coordinate system yields radial and azimuthal accelerations, same would be the case with 2-D polar coordinates. Though it seems it cannot be extended like that. Any other input as to why this lazy extension of mine was not valid apart from the obvious mathematics?

Comment: Will radial and azimuthal remain zero for any linear trajectory? Non-constant velocity and non-parallel to X-Y axes? If this is so, then is there a way of thinking about it without actually solving for the accelerations?